# How to form a pattern of X in the format of a box but instead every line the position of X alternates?

Tags: python, design-patterns

if anybody could help me with this problem it would be a great help. SO the task at hand is summarised into this:

Write a function named `diagonal(n)` that takes a positive integer parameter `n` and that prints an `n x n` box pattern with `X`s on all four sides and on the main diagonal. The illustration shows the desired output for `n = 9`.

```
XXXXXXXXX
XX      X
X X     X
X  X    X
X   X   X
X    X  X
X     X X
X      XX
XXXXXXXXX
```

So my progress so far is:

```
def diagonal(n):

    for row in range(n):

        for col in range(1):

            print("X", end="")

        print()

diagonal(7)
```

If somebody could help me out, I would appreciate it big time.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibile solution:

```py
def diagonal(n):
    row = ""
    for i in range(1, (n+1)):
        for j in range(1, (n+1)):
            if(i == 1 or i == n or j == 1 or j == n or i == j):
                row = row + "X"
            else:
                row = row + " "
        print(row)
        row = ""
```

```
diagonal(9)

XXXXXXXXX
XX      X
X X     X
X  X    X
X   X   X
X    X  X
X     X X
X      XX
XXXXXXXXX
```